# Re-Encrypt to more people after the first encrypt

Tags: encryption, epa

Let's say I create a file with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> `file.gpg`, then save it with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd>. I get to this buffer:

```
Select recipients for encryption.
If no one is selected, symmetric encryption will be performed.  
- `M-x epa-mark-key' to mark a key on the line
- `M-x epa-unmark-key' to unmark a key on the line
[Cancel][OK]

  u 372XXXXX Jane Doe <jane@doe.com>
  u A4DXXXXX John Doe <john@doe.com>
```

and I mark `372XXXXX` as the recipient. Now I have a `file.gpg` that's decryptable by `372XXXXX`'s private key.

After a time I decide I want to add `A4DXXXXX` to the recipients, so that it's decryptable by `372XXXXX` **and** `A4DXXXXX`.

Is there any **sane** option except copy-pasting the full contents, creating a new file and then marking the keys anew? I found `epa-file-select-keys` but that apparently only opens the selection buffer without doing any actual change to the file, so when I clear the GPG cache and reload file with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-v</kbd> I only get prompted for the first marked key (`372XXXXX`).

When I mark 2+ keys (`372XXXXX` + `A4DXXXXX`) in the beginning (from scratch when creating the file, no re-encryption), it'll ask for 2+ marked keys just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it seems to work, but in a bit strange way.

If I don't have the key's password cached yet, I'll get prompted automatically with [`epa-file-select-keys`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7945d86829d89066f082f0086047fae34cf932f1/lisp/epa-file.el#L343) dialog even after saving file multiple times -- which is one way of making it work.

After the password is cached, [`epa-file-select-keys`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7945d86829d89066f082f0086047fae34cf932f1/lisp/epa-file.el#L343) doesn't prompt anymore. It still is the go to func though.

Now when I want to add a new recipient/key, [`epa-file-select-keys`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7945d86829d89066f082f0086047fae34cf932f1/lisp/epa-file.el#L343) is *only a [variable changing](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7945d86829d89066f082f0086047fae34cf932f1/lisp/epa-file.el#L346) function* via `setq-local` and requires manual saving **yet again** even though the buffer is marked as unchanged, therefore a <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> does nothing and outputs only `(No changes need to be saved)`.

Therefore at least one change is necessary, for which I simply either add+remove a space or a new line.

Although this seems like the [`epa-file-select-keys`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/7945d86829d89066f082f0086047fae34cf932f1/lisp/epa-file.el#L343)'s fault, most likely it's not messing with the buffer's state directly so that it's usable in custom code (which marking a buffer as changed would make harder).